# Assembly Programming: Why are function arguments always memory locations?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am brand new to assembly programming and I was wondering why the address of a variable is always pushed to the stack instead of the actual variable. For example:

```
.text:00401270 push ebp

.text:00401271 mov ebp, esp

.text:00401273 sub esp, 80h

.text:00401279 push offset aString1

.text:0040127E call sub_401554
```

Why is the actual variable never pushed as an argument?

Comment: You could.  But then the string can't have more than 4 characters, not very practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all "function" arguments are necessarily passed by reference, but your example is a string, which is passed by reference due to its variable size being inappropriate on the stack.

The specifics of how you call a function and clean up before returning will vary depending upon the calling convention with which you are to interface.

If your callers will always be assembly code you control, you might choose to pass short arguments on the stack, but passing pointers lets you use data structures which are larger and more complicated, and thus more likely candidates for needing hand-coded-assembly optimization.

Comment: A string is not passed by reference.  It is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element and then passed by value.  Important but small difference!

Comment: @fuz in pure assembly, I believe that it (still) is - there's no implicit conversion going on. From a C or C++ caller, the string being passed by pointer value and not by reference aliasing is usefully distinct but I think it's not relevant on this Q&A, but it's been an age since I was writing that close to the metal (on purpose).